# FFTW: Inverse transform of forward transform of 1/cosh function is wrong

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fftw

I'm attempting to take the inverse transform of a complex 1D arrays forward transform in Fortran 90 and fftw. However, the output I receive from the inverse transform is at times completely different from the original input, whereas some values possess an incorrect real section but a correct imaginary part and a few match the original values perfectly.

I've noticed that this issue disappears if dx (the spacing between x values) is reduced to 0.01. Increasing n to compensate for this reduction in x's range then results in the issue resurfacing.

At this point, I believe the issue lies in the 1/cosh segment of the input array as I've been able to replace this with other complex inputs with no issues.
This code is adapted from a MATLAB file in which the form of the input only differs due to MATLAB using sech instead of 1/cosh.

Fortran isn't my 'go to' language so I'm wondering if I've made some normally obvious mistake due to my familiarity with python/matlab .

As for more specifics on the outputs,

The matlab version of this code produces the same values for the in array but the operation of the forward transform and the inverse transform produce different results,

**Matlab**

`out2(2) =    5.5511e-17 + 6.9389e-18i`
`out2(3) =    5.5511e-17 - 1.3878e-17i`
`out2(4) =    5.5511e-17 + 2.7756e-17i`
`out2(1024) =  0.9938 + 0.0994i`
`out2(2048) =  0 - 1.3878e-17i`

**Fortran**

`out2(2) = -5.5511151231257827E-017 - 6.9388939039072284E-018i`
`out2(3) = 0.0000000000000000 +  1.3877787807814457E-017i`
`out2(4) = 0.0000000000000000 + 0.0000000000000000i`
`out(1024) = 0.99380163159683255 + 9.9410098890158616E-002i`
`out2(2048) = -5.5511151231257827E-017 - 6.9388939039072284E-018i`

```
PROGRAM FFTEXAMPLE
implicit none
include 'fftw3.f'

INTEGER :: n, j, nindex, i
REAL :: dx
DOUBLE COMPLEX, ALLOCATABLE :: in(:), out(:), in2(:), out2(:)
REAL(kind = 8), ALLOCATABLE :: x(:)
INTEGER*8 :: plan, plan2

nindex = 11
n = 2 ** nindex
dx = 0.05   ! Spacing between x array values

allocate( in(n), out(n), x(n), in2(n), out2(n) )


CALL dfftw_plan_dft_1d( plan, n, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE )
CALL dfftw_plan_dft_1d( plan2, n, in2, out2, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE )

x = (/ (-dx*n/2 + (i-1)*dx, i=1, n) /)  ! Seeds x array from -51.2 to 51.15

! Create values for the input array
DO j = 1, n, 1
    in(j) = 1/cosh ( x(j)/1.0040 ) * exp( (0.0, -1.0) * 1.9940 * x(j) )
END DO

CALL dfftw_execute_dft( plan, in, out ) ! FWD transform

!DO j = 1, n, 1
!   in2(j) = cmplx(REAL(out(j)), AIMAG(out(j)))
!END DO

in2 = out

CALL dfftw_execute_dft( plan2, in2, out2 ) ! Inverse transform

out2 = out2/n  ! Divide output by n to normalise

CALL dfftw_destroy_plan( plan )
CALL dfftw_destroy_plan( plan2 )

END PROGRAM
```

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that `REAL` without any `kind` is single precision? Consequently, you calculate the `cosh` and the subsequent division in single precision... I would expect some losses here! Could you convert your code to double precision? Maybe that solves your problem...

Comment: Append `D0` to all the literals as well

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong (though I would make comments on certain language "features" given more space), and running the code shows FFTW gives a correct forward and backward pair. Could you quantify what you mean by statements like "completely" wrong by giving some numbers - not all of us have quick access to Matlab to recreate the original.

Comment: @IanBush I've added some examples from the matlab/fortran outputs after taking the backward/inverse transform. Hope this helps.

Comment: Floating point maths is not the same as real maths and it won't agree from implementation to implementation. Why do you think the above Fortran numbers are wrong? From a few decades of experience they are as good as, in fact better, than I would expect but to do it properly requires some proper numerical analysis which, to be honest, is beyond my knowledge. Have you done that?

Comment: It seems the part of my brain that distinguishes between numerical and analytical methods took the last few days off. I definitely need to read up more on the actual methods involved in FFTs. 
Having performed a more in-depth comparison between the matlab and Fortran results (After switching to double precision) I can see that they are actually giving the same overall result.
It appears that I was just being overly pedantic and numerically unenlightened about the results close to the boundary points!
Thank you, this has been really helpful getting me on the right track.